# Disable dropping of links or images on input?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

How can I disable people to drop links or images on an input box? I can use JavaScript or even jQuery.

I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/eRqzz/

```
$("input#fl_search, input#fl_search_bdy").on('drop', function (e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your fiddle, except you need to add a library from the top left dropdown (jQuery in this case)

[image]

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Vp4yF/)

```
$("input#fl_search, input#fl_search_bdy").on('drop', function (e){
     e.preventDefault();
});
```